# Can we capture all domains of discouse in the predicate logic within categorical logic?

Tags: logic, category-theory, predicate-logic, foundations, motivation

In the construction of the bounded quantifiers via adjoints in the fibered category of subsets over a set (see e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_functor#Categorical_logic) on Wikipedia), is there any restriction on the sets - specifically regarding cardinality?

I essentially ask this because it feels like the aim is to fully describe first order predicate logic internally in a category - however as set theory is generally build over predicate logic, I'm not sure how natural it is to assume the logical universe of discourse to be some set from the start.

Comment: Would either of the `motivation` or `foundations` tags be appropriate here? It might help to include them.

Comment: @Shaun: You really want an answer, don'tcha :). [This](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8731/categorical-foundations-without-set-theory) MathOverflow question is a related question and makes me think the answer really comes down to how much set theory (or incarnations of set theory axioms, postulating restricting information about the logical domain of discourse) must be used in the approach of doing predicate logic in those fibre categories. Maybe there are even other ways - I came to ask the question when reading "Categorical Logic and Type Theory - Jacobs B.", available online.

Comment: Absolutely. Thank you, Nick. That helps a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

for this part of the question

> the aim is to fully describe first order predicate logic internally in a category

there are papers very close to that theme at Steve Awodey's web site, including:

> http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/awodey/preprints/fold.pdf
>   "In the present work, we generalize [Stone duality for Boolean algebras] from
>   propositional to first-order logic. Boolean algebras are replaced by
>   Boolean categories presented by theories in first-order logic, and spaces
>   of models are replaced by topological groupoids of models and their
>   isomorphisms."

and

> http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/awodey/preprints/BSL.pdf
>   "We show how to interpret  the language of first-order set theory in an elementary topos endowed with, as extra structure, a directed structural system of inclusions (dssi).... we thus obtain a first-order set theory whose associated categories of sets are exactly the elementay toposes."